# How to convert BSON::Timestamp to ruby time and vice versa

Tags: ruby, mongodb, timestamp, bson

I have a ruby hash

`input = {"dateCreated"=>#<BSON::Timestamp:0x00007fe0b482ca98 @increment=3745289216, @seconds=229>}`

1. how do we extract time from BSON timestamp class.

tried input["dateCreated"].as_json
`=> {"$timestamp"=>{"t"=>244, "i"=>664779776}}`

Not sure how to proceed.

2. Also would appreciate if there is any pointer on how to filter based on timestamp value to MongoDB using ruby driver

`.find()` method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert a [`BSON::Timestamp`](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/mongodb/bson-ruby/BSON/Timestamp) to a [`BSON::ByteBuffer`](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/mongodb/bson-ruby/BSON/ByteBuffer) using the `#to_bson` method.

You can then convert the `BSON::ByteBuffer` to an integer (`#get_int64`) that represents the number of milliseconds since the epoch.

Then use [`Time::at`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Time.html#method-c-at) to convert that integer to a `Time` object

```
date_time = DateTime.new(2021,8,30)
date_time.to_time
#=> 2021-08-30 00:00:00 +0000
date_time.to_time.to_i
#=> 1630281600 
timestamp = BSON::Timestamp.from_bson(date_time.to_bson)
#=> #<BSON::Timestamp:0x00007fffe31da4a8 @seconds=379, @increment=2488994816>
timestamp.to_bson.get_int64 / 1000 
#=> 1630281600
Time.at(timestamp.to_bson.get_int64 / 1000).utc
#=> 2021-08-30 00:00:00 UTC
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you hace an object of this type:

https://www.rubydoc.info/github/mongodb/bson-ruby/BSON/Timestamp

from this [gem](https://github.com/mongodb/bson-ruby)

and this [object](https://docs.mongodb.com/ruby-driver/current/tutorials/bson-v4/#bson-timestamp)

```
[6] pry(main)> bt = BSON::Timestamp.new(229, 3745289216)
=> #<BSON::Timestamp:0x00007fe338a79680 @increment=3745289216, @seconds=229>
[7] pry(main)> # you allready have when begin the object in second 229
[8] pry(main)> # you allready have when finish the even in secons in atribute increment 3745289216
```

may be this value are chage because time begins in 1970 son for translating settings and using a handy gem for manipulating times used in rails:

```
[10] pry(main)> DateTime.strptime(bt.seconds.to_s,'%s')
=> #<DateTime: 1970-01-01T00:03:49+00:00 ((2440588j,229s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>

[13] pry(main)> require 'active_support/core_ext/numeric/time.rb'
=> true

[14] pry(main)> DateTime.strptime(bt.seconds.to_s,'%s') + bt.increment.seconds
=> Mon, 06 Sep 2088 06:10:45 +0000
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. But in mongo I created a date field and gave 2021-08-30T07:00:00.000+00:00 and changed the data type as timestamp. the value changed as 1630306800000. When I do Time.at(1630306800000/1000) the value is right. but mongo results in BSON format

bt = #<BSON::Timestamp:0x00007fc504b12f30 @increment=2514194816, @seconds=379>
[66] pry(main)> DateTime.strptime(bt.seconds.to_s,'%s')
=> Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:06:19 +0000
[67] pry(main)> DateTime.strptime(bt.seconds.to_s,'%s') + bt.increment.seconds
=> Thu, 02 Sep 2049 11:33:15 +0000

the final value is mismatching?