# How to filter mongo based on timestamp using ruby driver

Tags: ruby, mongodb, mongodb-query, timestamp

{
"name" : "A",
"timestamp" : 1048636800000
}

Say this is a sample doc in the mongo collection. I'm tryng to filter records based on timestamp value using mongo **ruby** driver

````
connection[:collection].find({"timestamp"=>{"$lte"=>Time.now}}).to_a 

connection[:collection].find({"timestamp"=>{"$lte"=>Time.at(1048636800000/1000)}}).to_a 

connection[:collection].find({"timestamp"=>{"$lte"=>Time.parse("2003-03-26 05:30:00 +0530")}}).to_a ```

all empty results.
````

Comment: It seems to be a measurement units mismatch. Timestamp in Mongo seems to be in milliseconds, in Ruby you get seconds by default. So Ruby timestamp converted into integer will be ~1000 times smaller than its equivalent in Mongo (so your condition `timestamp => { $lte => <some timestamp sent from Ruby> }` is always false). Try smth like `"$lte"=> (Time.now.to_i * 1000)` - chances are this could help

Answer (score 0):

Given your [Other Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69043995/how-to-convert-bsontimestamp-to-ruby-time-and-vice-versa)

You are likely looking for

```
connection[:collection].find({"timestamp"=>{"$lte"=>Time.now.to_bson.get_int64}})
```

That being said @KonstantinStrukov's comment is correct that this results in milliseconds meaning that `Time.now.to_i * 1000` will work equally well